# How to send an auto-welcome message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to make that my bot would send an auto-welcome message to new members.
Here is the code that didn't work:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
            member.guild.users.get(`${member.id}`).send("Heyo!"); 
        });
```

Do you know a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`member` already has a `send()` method.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {      
   member.send("Heyo!")
      .catch(console.error);
});
```

[Documentation on GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

Comment: `GuildMember#send()` is a valid method [As Seen Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send), you'll need to do some logging and make sure the recieving member has Direct Messages from Server Members enabled